# Inconsistent font rendering in terminal

Tags: fonts

I tried to install Hack font from ryanoasis/nerd-fonts with this method:
https://github.com/source-foundry/hack-linux-installer

But I still got a issue for the rendering in my gnome terminal I got this:
[wrong font rendering terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCAix.png)

And from atom I got this:
[atom render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2uWQ.png)

The fonts seems to be installed well:

```
$ fc-list | grep Hack                                    
/home/yumiki/.local/share/fonts/Hack-BoldItalic.ttf: Hack:style=Bold Italic
/home/yumiki/.local/share/fonts/Hack-Italic.ttf: Hack:style=Italic
/home/yumiki/.local/share/fonts/Hack-Regular.ttf: Hack:style=Regular
/home/yumiki/.local/share/fonts/Hack-Bold.ttf: Hack:style=Bold
```

Comment: Looks like the font is not properly UTF-8 compliant.

Comment: @Matigo Sorry I'm a noob about font, what does that mean? 
On Hack repository I can see that it support these character set:
"Character set support: ASCII, Latin-1, Latin Extended A, Greek, Cyrillic "

Comment: No worries. We're all "n00bs" at some point. The character sets that you listed above are "incomplete". A lot of applications, including terminal, need to have UTF-8 compliant fonts if they are to show characters correctly without the weird boxes all over the place.